# Vector size not zero on initialization

Tags: c++, vector, omnet++, inet

I am using inet v3.4.0. I am trying to create a mobility model. But whenever I create a std::vector of any type, it is initialized with random size.

When initialized it never have a zero size. Is that supposed to happen? because from C++ vector, I see that on creation of vector e.g.

```
std::vector <int*> a;
```

`a` should have a size of zero.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. To be more precise - how are checking the size? In addition `std::vector a;` will not compile, since it is missing template arguments.

Comment: Also, even if you're working with OMNeT++, is your problem really related to it? When editing your question to include the MCVE, also make sure you don't have any unrelated tags.

Comment: My crystal ball thinks you're trying to determine the size with `sizeof(a)` rather than `a.size()`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Good spot. You could answer on that basis, you know. If not, I'm tempted to pinch that.

Comment: @Bathsheba Too much conjecture for an answer in itself, I think.

Answer (score 7):

On the contrary; the C++ standard *requires* a default constructed `std::vector` to have zero size:

```
std::vector<int* /*for example, but the type is not relevant*/> a;
a.size() == 0; // this is true
a.empty(); // this is true
```

Are you using your debugger to inspect the apparent "contents" of `a`? Note that a `std::vector` may be constructed with a non-zero *capacity*, as a memory management optimisation.

(Acknowledge @molbdnilo: You can't use `sizeof(a)` to return the number of elements in `a`.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is inet, but I get size as 0 using C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        std::vector<int*> a;
        cout << "Size is : " << a.size() << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Size is : 0
```